# Convenient way to relabel vector in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am creating a new column called `Damage_new`, but feel this way is slugish.

Can someone help with a simple way to achieve the following

```
MyData$Damage_new[0<=MyData$Damage & MyData$Damage<=30] <- 0
MyData$Damage_new[40<=MyData$Damage & MyData$Damage<=50] <- 1
MyData$Damage_new[60<=MyData$Damage & MyData$Damage<=70] <- 2
MyData$Damage_new[80<=MyData$Damage & MyData$Damage<=100] <- 3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `help('findInterval')`.

Comment: Your example code is odd in that ignores damage values from 31-39, from 51-59, and from 71-79. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes, intentional

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a function that does this, but i don't know. So doing it with a loop:

```
cond = cbind(c(0,40,60,80), c(30,50,70,100), c(0,1,2,3))
for(i in 1:nrow(cond)){
  MyData$Damage_new[cond[i,1]<=MyData$Damage & MyData$Damage<=cond[i,2]] = cond[i,3]}
```

You could generalize it a bit more by creating `cond` with `seq`, than you can easily change the condition (as long as it follows a PA sequence):

```
cond = cbind(c(0,seq(40,80,20)), c(seq(30,70,20),100), seq(0,3,1))
```